# Hosted static analysis tool for C++

Tags: c++, code-analysis, continuous-integration

[CodeClimate](https://codeclimate.com/) is a great tool for analysing JavaScript/Ruby code but sadly it does not support C++ yet.

Where could I find a similar tool that:

- analyses C++ code for quality and performance.
- integrates easily with [GitHub](http://github.com) or [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/).
- is free for Open Source projects.

Comment: What platform OS?

Comment: I am looking for a hosted service. I don't want to run it on my computer. It should be part of a continuous integration build, and run et each GitHub commit / each Travis build.

Answer (score 2):

The best bet is [coverity](https://scan.coverity.com/).

- Hosted
- Java, C/C++ or C# code
- Runs on open source project for free
- Integrates [easily](https://scan.coverity.com/github) with GitHub and Travis

It is subject to a maximum number of builds per day/week, 3 per day and 12 per week. If less then 10k lines down to 2 per week for projects greater than 1M lines.

Comment: I looked into Coverity, but my main problem is that it [cannot be triggered on pull-requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759088/run-coverity-scan-for-every-travis-pull-request-build), which is a no-go for me. Also, I didn't find any way of customizing the rules for the scan, but maybe I just didn't dig enough.

Comment: I would really like SonarQube, but like the OP, I'm looking for a hosted solution.